# How to display float values in SpinEdit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have a simple dialog with a SpinEdit control thot is supposed to work with integers and float values. It works correctly with integers, however it doesn't load float values. THe float value is loaded correctly to my Property but once the dialog opens it shows '0,00' instead of, say, '44,44'. If my float value has no decimal numbers it is also loaded correctly, so I can see values like '44,00'.

I tried casting to Decimal but to no avail. The only difference is that the value in my property has a dot '.' as a decimal placeholder while the SpinEdit shows a comma. From what I've read that shouldn't be a problem.
Here's my SpinEdit:

XAML:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TInputNumericVM}">
     <dxe:SpinEdit x:Name="dxSpinEdit" 
                   Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   MaskType="Numeric"
                   IsFloatValue="{Binding FloatValue}"
                   MinValue="{Binding MinValue}"
                   MaxValue="{Binding MaxValue}"
                   Mask="{Binding Mask, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   MaxLength="{Binding Path=InputLength}"
                   MaskShowPlaceHolders="{Binding ShowPlaceHolder}"
                   InvalidValueBehavior="WaitForValidValue"
                   MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True"
                   AllowRoundOutOfRangeValue="True"
                   Increment="{Binding IncrementStep}"
                   />
  </DataTemplate>
```

With 'IsFloatVakue = true', 'Mask = f', 'MaskShowPlaceholders = True'

EDIT:

I have managed to display the float value with a temporary workaround. I threw away the MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" property and used FormatDisplayString property where I set the value to "###.##". I'm not satisfied with this solution, but it works for now, the question is still opened and I'd appreciate further suggestions.

EDIT2:

I'm working on devexpress ver 16.1.6 and after consultations with my colleague he suggests that the MaskUseAsDisplayFormat property may work properly on a newr version but I can't use the newer version so I won't be checking it.

Comment: Have you tried hard-coding IsFloatValue and Mask instead of binding them?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič Yes, I've tried that. I double checked just now and set: Mask="f" and IsFloatValue="True". No luck.

Comment: What about Mask = "F2"?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič I tried it and it works the same. I can input a value with 2 decimal numbers but the value the spinEdit displays at the start is still 0,0. I also tried Mask="##.##" but that displays the comma lone without any value. Unless the value loaded is an integer, then it displays it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the SpinEdit as well to display float/double values. Here is the code, which works for me:

```xml
<dxe:SpinEdit MinValue="1" Increment="0.5" 
              Mask="f1" MaskUseAsDisplayFormat="True" IsTextEditable="True"              
              EditValueType="{x:Type system:Double}"
              EditValue="{Binding Path=XYZ, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Guess the important properties to set are "Mask" and "EditValueType".

Using DevExpress 17.2.4.